# Java DAO Pattern - Separate Database Communication Responsibility Without Using Multiple Classes

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao

Hoping to leverage the knowledge of the community to help me answer a question on the DAO pattern in Java Programming.

Searching google for examples of implementing the DAO pattern give results like this:[Example DAO Pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHHen.png)

```
  public class DaoPatternDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      StudentDao studentDao = new StudentDaoImpl();

      //print all students
      for (Student student : studentDao.getAllStudents()) {
         System.out.println("Student: [RollNo : " + student.getRollNo() + ", Name : " + student.getName() + " ]");
      }


      //update student
      Student student =studentDao.getAllStudents().get(0);
      student.setName("Michael");
      studentDao.updateStudent(student);

      //get the student
      studentDao.getStudent(0);
      System.out.println("Student: [RollNo : " + student.getRollNo() + ", Name : " + student.getName() + " ]");     
   }
}
```

My question is this: Is there a clean way to utilize just the Student model/class to communicate with the database on behalf of students rather than implement a "StudentDao" class as well? I would much rather do something like this:

```
student.setName("Michael");
```

and have the Student class handle all the database communication to set the name of the student upon calling the `setName()` method rather than have to do this:

```
student.setName("Michael");
studentDao.updateStudent(student);
```

It seems like if you follow the DAO pattern you have to do everything twice: Update the Student Object and the Student Table in the Database. Wouldn't it be easier to just have the methods in the Student Class take care of updating the database as well? What would be the drawbacks of a design like that?

(Example code and image taken from: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is something called Active Record (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern), where the model itself is responsible for managing its persistence. i haven‘t worked with it in java but i remember this library. have a look, maybe thats what you‘re looking for.
https://javalite.io/activejdbc

drawback is that you‘re binding your domain model directly to your persistence layer and you risk that your models become purely data containers with only getters and setters. for simple crud applications i think this pattern is ok, but i wouldn’t use it for modeling complex domains.